# add dynamic cookie to spring integration request

Tags: spring, cookies, header, integration

I want to send a cookie as part of an HTTP service request. The name of the cookie is _br_uid_2, and the value of the cookie should be the customerId property of payload object.

The service is configured like so:

```
<int:channel id="InChannelBr"></int:channel>
<int:channel id="OutChannelBr"></int:channel>

<!-- Gateway Start -->
<int:gateway id="BloomreachGateway" default-request-timeout="5000" default-reply-timeout="5000" 
default-request-channel="InChannelBr" service-interface="com.someco.service.BloomreachSpringService">
    <int:method name="getSearchResults" request-channel="InChannelBr" reply-channel="OutChannelBr" />       
</int:gateway>  

<int-http:outbound-gateway id="locationBloomreachGateway"
                           request-channel="InChannelBr"
                           reply-channel="OutChannelBr"
                           url="${bloomreach_search_url}?account_id=${br_account_id}&amp;auth_key=${br_auth_key}&amp;domain_key=${br_domain_key}&amp;url=${br_url}&amp;request_type=${br_request_type}&amp;br_origin=${br_origin}&amp;search_type=${br_search_type}&amp;fl=${br_field_list}{urlParams}&amp;facet.range=${br_price_range}"
                           http-method="GET"
                           encode-uri="false"
                           transfer-cookies="true"
                           reply-timeout='5000'
                           expected-response-type="com.someco.BloomreachSearchResponse"
                           message-converters="brJsonConverter"
                           uri-variables-expression="@brUriVariablesBean.populate(payload)">
</int-http:outbound-gateway>
```

This seems like a common desire, but I didn't see any clear documentation on it. I looked at Transformers and Header Enrichers.

Can someone tell me how to update the Spring service definition so it sends payload.getCustomerId() as the value of a _br_uid_2 cookie?

Thanks!
Bobby

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I added a header-enricher with name="Cookie" expression="'_br_uid_2=' + payload.customerId".

```
<int:channel id="InChannelBr"></int:channel>
<int:channel id="InChannelBrWithCookies"></int:channel>
<int:channel id="OutChannelBr"></int:channel>

<!-- Gateway Start -->
<int:gateway id="BloomreachGateway" default-request-timeout="5000" default-reply-timeout="5000" 
default-request-channel="InChannelBr" service-interface="com.someco.service.BloomreachSpringService">
    <int:method name="getSearchResults" request-channel="InChannelBr" reply-channel="OutChannelBr" />       
</int:gateway>  

<int:header-enricher input-channel="InChannelBr" output-channel="InChannelBrWithCookies">
    <int:header name="Cookie" expression="'_br_uid_2=' + payload.customerId"/>
</int:header-enricher>

<int-http:outbound-gateway id="locationBloomreachGateway"
                           request-channel="InChannelBrWithCookies"
                           reply-channel="OutChannelBr"
                           url="${bloomreach_search_url}?account_id=${br_account_id}&amp;auth_key=${br_auth_key}&amp;domain_key=${br_domain_key}&amp;url=${br_url}&amp;request_type=${br_request_type}&amp;br_origin=${br_origin}&amp;search_type=${br_search_type}&amp;fl=${br_field_list}{urlParams}&amp;facet.range=${br_price_range}"
                           http-method="GET"
                           encode-uri="false"
                           transfer-cookies="true"
                           reply-timeout='5000'
                           expected-response-type="com.someco.BloomreachSearchResponse"
                           message-converters="brJsonConverter"
                           uri-variables-expression="@brUriVariablesBean.populate(payload)">
</int-http:outbound-gateway>
```